# Parameter specified as non-null is null:Can't Update individual Entity field in Spring Boot jpa. Caused Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin

Recently, I am learning Spring boot with Postgrasql as Database. All of my POST, GET, DELETE methods work perfectly without PUT method. What I want is to update individual field of entity. But if I don't update all field, it says 'Parameter specified as non-null is null'

My code is

`User.kt`

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import javax.persistence.*
import javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_info")
data class User(
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "user_seq",
        sequenceName = "user_seq",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = SEQUENCE,
        generator = "user_seq"
    )
    @Column(
        name = "id",
        updatable = false
    )
    val id: Long = -1,

    @Column(
        name = "first_name",
        nullable = false,
        length = 50,
        updatable = true
    )
    val firstName: String,

    @Column(
        name = "last_name",
        nullable = false,
        length = 50,
        updatable = true
    )
    val lastName: String,

    @Column(
        name = "email",
        nullable = true,
        length = 150,
        updatable = true
    )
    val email: String,

    @Column(
        name = "gender",
        nullable = false,
        length = 2,
        updatable = true
    )
    val gender: String,

    @Column(
        name = "date_of_birth",
        nullable = false,
        updatable = true
    )
    val dateOfBirth: LocalDate,

    @Column(
        name = "country",
        nullable = false,
        length = 50,
        updatable = true
    )
    val country: String
)
```

`UserController.kt`

package com.example.demo.user

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import java.time.LocalDate

@RestController
@RequestMapping(
    path = [
        "/api/v1/"
    ]
)
class UserController(
    @Autowired private val userService: UserService
) {

    @PutMapping("update/{id}")
    fun updateUser(
        @PathVariable("id") id: Long,
        @RequestParam(required = false) firstName: String,
        @RequestParam(required = false) lastName: String,
        @RequestParam(required = false) email: String,
        @RequestParam(required = false) gender: String,
        @RequestParam(required = false) country: String,
        @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE) dateOfBirth: LocalDate
    ) {
        return userService.updateUser(id, firstName, lastName, email, gender, country, dateOfBirth)
    }
}
```

`UserService.kt`

```
package com.example.demo.user

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import java.time.LocalDate

@Service
class UserService(
    @Autowired private val userRepository: UserRepository
) {

    fun registerUser(user: User) {
        if (userRepository.findUserByEmail(user.email).isPresent) throw IllegalStateException("Email Already taken")
        userRepository.save(user)
    }

    fun getUsers(offset: Int): List<User> {
        return userRepository.getUsers(offset)
    }

    fun getUserInfo(userId: Long): User {
        if (!userRepository.existsById(userId)) throw IllegalArgumentException("User not found")
        return userRepository.findById(userId).get()
    }

    fun deleteUser(userId: Long) {
        if (!userRepository.existsById(userId)) throw IllegalStateException("User with id $userId does not exist")
        userRepository.deleteById(userId)
    }

    @Transactional
    fun updateUser(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, gender: String, country: String, dateOfBirth: LocalDate) {
        val user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow { throw IllegalStateException("User with id $id does not exist") }

//        if (userRepository.findUserByEmail(user.email).isPresent) throw IllegalStateException("Email Already taken")
        if (firstName.isNotEmpty()) user.firstName = firstName
        if (lastName.isNotEmpty()) user.lastName = lastName
        if (email.isNotEmpty()) user.email = email
        if (gender.isNotEmpty() && (gender == "M" || gender == "F")) user.gender = gender
        if (country.isNotEmpty()) user.country = country
        if (dateOfBirth.toString().isNotEmpty()) user.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
    }

}
```

Response payload is

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-02T11:45:27.025+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.demo.user.UserController.updateUser, parameter dateOfBirth",
    "path": "/api/v1/update/1000"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the UserService code ?

Comment: @AnthonyChatellier added. Please Check

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from your REST controller. The request params are annotated with required=false but the type is String. So when an HTTP request comes with null values, Spring can't deserialize data in those fields. (That explains the NullpointerException.

You have to provide nullable types (like "String?") In your controller and this nullability should not necessariry proliferate in all layers of your code.

For example "firstname" is optional for update but mandatory for creation.

Comment: thanks for your response. After add nullable type in my my controller class
I got 'Internal Server Error'

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked much on kotlin but what I think the issue is Kotlin is null-safe programming language. You need to explicitly tell if variable can be null or not. For more detail please refer this [blog](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html). Updating your entity class with field accepting null should work.

for example To allow nulls, you can declare a variable as nullable string, written `String?:`

Comment: thanks for your response. After add nullable type in my my controller class
I got 'Internal Server Error'

Comment: Add nullability to controller and entity both